# The sub request has returned several values

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Artfacture 
(
     N int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
     Code varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     Ht Numeric NOT NULL 
)

INSERT INTO Artfacture (N, Code, Ht) 
VALUES ('1', '1', '10'), ('1', '2', '20'),('1', '3', '30');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Facture 
(
     N int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
     Ht Numeric NOT NULL 
)

INSERT INTO Facture (N, Ht) 
VALUES ('1', '60');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Article 
(
     Code varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
     Famille varchar(50) NOT NULL 
)

INSERT INTO Article (Code, Famille) 
VALUES ('1', 'F1'), ('2', 'F2'), ('3', 'F3');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Farticle 
(
     Designation varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
     Compte varchar(50) NOT NULL 
)

INSERT INTO Farticle (Designation, Compte)  
VALUES ('F1', '700000'), ('F2', '710000'), ('F3', '720000');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Ecritures 
(
     Date Date,
     Pièce varchar(50) NOt NULL,
     Compte varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
     Aux varchar(50),
     Libelle varchar(100) NOT NULL,
     Débit numeric NOT NULL
     Crédit numeric NOT NULL  
)
```

My request is a trigger where adding, updating or deleting some new rows in table `Facture`, it must add, update, delete rows in `Ecritures` with the same numbers of rows of `Artfacture`

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_Facture] 
ON [dbo].[Facture]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
AS
     DECLARE @dat AS date,
             @piece AS nvarchar(10),
             @piece1 AS nvarchar(10),
             @de money, @cr money, 
             @code AS nvarchar(255),
             @compte AS nvarchar(50),
             @Aux AS nvarchar(50),
             @lib AS nvarchar(50),
             @Famille AS nvarchar(255)

     SET @de = 0
     SET @Aux = ''
     SET @piece = (SELECT [N] FROM inserted)
     SET @piece1= (SELECT [N] FROM deleted)
     SET @dat = (SELECT [Date] FROM [dbo].[Facture] WHERE [N] = @piece)
     SET @lib = 'FACTURE DE VENTE - ' + (SELECT [Societe] FROM [dbo].[Facture] WHERE [N] = @piece)
     SET @Compte = (SELECT F.CompteV FROM Artfacture AF 
                    INNER JOIN Article A ON A.Code = AF.Code 
                    INNER JOIN Farticle F ON F.Designation = A.Famille 
                    WHERE N = @piece)
     set @Cr = (select AF.Ht from Artfacture AF inner join Article A on A.Code = AF.Code where N = @piece)
     begin
     IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted )
     insert into F_Ecritures (Date,Piece,Compte,Auxiliere,Libelle,Débit,Crédit)
     select @dat,@piece,F.CompteV,@Aux,@lib,@de, AF.Ht
     from Artfacture AF
     inner join F_Article A on A.Code = AF.Code
     inner join F_Farticle F on F.Designation = A.Famille
     where N = @piece
     group by F.CompteV, AF.Ht;
     ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
     update Ecritures set                            Date=@dat,Piece=@piece,Compte=@compte,Auxiliere=@Aux,Libelle=@lib,Débit=@de,Crédit=@cr where Piece=@piece          and Compte=@Compte
     ELSE IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)

         DELETE FROM [dbo].[Ecritures] WHERE Piece = @piece1
     end
```

The problem is that I get an error that the subrequest has returned several values .....

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The first code isn't T-SQL for sure, while the second one is a T-SQL. So what's the rdbms you're really using?

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: is sqlserver, excuse me

Comment: Triggers are run for the whole set of an update, not for each row. So this line will fail `SET @piece = (SELECT [N] FROM inserted)` as inserted is highly likely to contain more than 1 row.

Comment: how to fixe it, please ?

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Since the trigger operates on the whole set, you need to construct it something like this. The logic might not quite match what you were trying to do but you should be able to get the idea using this pattern.

```
update Ecritures set <column expressions>
from inserted
join ECritures on eCritures.Piece=inserted.N

insert ECritures(<column list>)
select <columnist>
from inserted 
where not exists(select * from deleted where deleted.Piece=inserted.N)

delete eCritures 
from eCritures
join deleted on eCritures.Piece=deleted.N
where not exists(select * from inserted where inserted.N=deleted.N)
```